# Is it possible to use concerns outside of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I like the idea of `ActiveSupport::Concerns` but wondering if possible to use in a vanilla Ruby app. Or is it only in a Rails app? I'm thinking of the example using ActiveRecord in a Sinatra app.

## Edit

Looks like you can by `requiring 'active_support'`, though I am not sure if any nuance about this doesn't work.

Like:

```
require 'active_support'

module Printable
  include ActiveSupport::Concern

  def print
    puts "I will print here"
  end
end


class User

  include Printable

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def say_my_name
    puts "my name: #{@name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Tim. Please try to avoid txtspk constructions like "thx" and "lmk" - real words should not be too much trouble to use here. Stack Overflow is more like documentation, and it isn't a chatroom. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can (and it seems like you've discovered how). Much of ActiveSupport is written in a way that it can be added by itself to other projects.

You can even require *just* `Concern` with `require "active_support/concern"`

#### Opinion

I'm generally against using `ActiveSupport::Concern` though:

- violates *Composition Over Inheritance* (see [Nothing is Something](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMPfEXIlTVE) by Sandi Metz)
- 95% of functionality is provided by vanilla Ruby already, in only 0-3 more lines of code (zero meaning you didn't need `Concern` *at all*)

Examples:

- The code snippet you've pasted works perfectly fine with a bare Ruby `module`
- [Rail's own documentation on `Concern`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) explains usage with vanilla Ruby examples of the same length and complexity
- In that documentation, it says: "Given a `Foo` module and a `Bar` module which depends on the former...", as if you'd *want* to deal with [mixin hell](https://raganwald.com/2016/07/16/why-are-mixins-considered-harmful.html)

Comment: Concerns can be tricky - I have found I end up special-casing more than I like in a concern (and have seen a lot of really egregious code in concerns) but if the topic of a concern is somewhat generic, I'm usually ok with it. An example that I'd agree with is https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/models/concerns/roleable.rb

Comment: Not a fan of `roleable` at all. It looks fine as "prettified prototype/hack code", but it'd be a real pain to maintain that (and all the things hard-coupled with that) after a few months of active development.